# Writing a Twig indent file for Sublime

Tags: sublimetext2, twig, indentation

So I'm at my wit's end on this one.  I want to adjust twig indentation to improve readability in sublime.  I can't seem to get the hang of it.  In the code below, my best guess is at the `***` mark.

How would I specify this better?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Miscellaneous</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>text.html</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>decreaseIndentPattern</key>
            <string>(?x)
            ^\s*
            (&lt;/(?!html)
              [A-Za-z0-9]+\b[^&gt;]*&gt;
            |--&gt;
            |&lt;\?(php)?\s+(else(if)?|end(if|for(each)?|while))
            |\}
            )</string>
            <key>increaseIndentPattern</key>
            <string>(?x)
            ^\s*
            &lt;(?!\?|area|base|br|col|frame|hr|html|img|input|link|meta|param|[^&gt;]*/&gt;)
              ([A-Za-z0-9]+)(?=\s|&gt;)\b[^&gt;]*&gt;(?!.*&lt;/\1&gt;)
            |&lt;!--(?!.*--&gt;)
            |&lt;\?php.+?\b(if|else(?:if)?|for(?:each)?|while)\b.*:(?!.*end\1)
   ***      |\{\%.*$
            |\{[^}"']*$
            </string>
            <key>bracketIndentNextLinePattern</key>
            <string>&lt;!DOCTYPE(?!.*&gt;)</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

Comment: 1) this has nothing to do with twig; 2) what exactly is your question? 3) I can't see the relationship with st2 too; 4) if you question is about editors, it should be posted on SuperUser, not SO

Comment: Twig customarily uses {% for its tags (see mark near ***).  Sublime2 customarily uses packages to specify syntax for languages.  The question relates to spcification of regular expression in xml format.  I'll go poke around SuperUser.  Question editted to indicate I am asking for the proper specification of the regular expression.